# API: Authorization failure Google Maps (blank screen)

Tags: android, api, google-maps, android-studio

I have a GoogleMaps fragment inside an activity and I simply cannot make it work. Every time I open it, the screen is blank and has only the "Set my location" icon. The map never shows up.

When I look at the LogCat, I get this:

```
01-11 22:53:22.984 29341-30537/package_name
E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
01-11 22:53:23.004 29341-30537/package_name E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
```

It is a clear sign that it is associated with the API so then I tried all the possible way to make that key work. These are the options that I have tried:

1. Creating an API code without any restriction [image: (Check link here)]. It didn't work!
2. Creating an API code with restriction to my app. I have used the package name and the code given both by the `google_maps.api.xml` file and using the Gradle signing report. The same error persisted. I even added multiple SHA-1 certificates corresponding to debug and release (from Google Play certificates).
3. Searching for Google Maps Android API v2 to enable. There is no such thing in my console. The only package (Google Maps Android API) is Enabled.
   [image: (See screenshot here)]

I wasted all the possible options that I could find on the internet. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

The only suspicious behavior that I can see now is that the `google_maps.api.xml` file has a (debug) extension written with grey color. I don't know if this has anything to do with this error. I see it like this: `google_maps.api.xml (debug)` in Android Studio.

```js
< manifest xmlns: android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package = "package" >

  <
  uses - permission android: name = "android.permission.INTERNET" / >
  <
  uses - permission android: name = "android.permission.CALL_PHONE" / >
  <
  uses - permission android: name = "android.permission.VIBRATE" / >
  <
  uses - permission android: name = "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" / >
  <
  uses - permission android: name = "android.permission.CAMERA" / >
  <
  uses - permission android: name = "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" / >
  <
  uses - permission android: name = "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" / >


  <
  application
android: allowBackup = "true"
android: icon = "@mipmap/app_logo"
android: label = "@string/app_name"
android: roundIcon = "@mipmap/app_logo"
android: supportsRtl = "true"
android: theme = "@style/AppTheme" >
  <
  activity android: name = ".MainScreenActivity" >
  <
  intent - filter >
  <
  action android: name = "android.intent.action.MAIN" / >

  <
  category android: name = "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" / >
  <
  /intent-filter> <
  /activity> <
  activity android: name = ".MainMenu" / >

  //And some other activities

  <
  meta - data
android: name = "com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
android: value = "@string/google_maps_key" / >

  <
  activity
android: name = ".Menu"
android: theme = "@style/AppTheme" / >
  //And some other activities
  <
  /application>

  <
  /manifest>
```

Comment: Is "@string/google_maps_key" valid? Make sure you have put a valid google_maps_key in your strings resources. Check to see that there aren't any other required keys/tokens/secrets that you have to add into your strings resources file as well.

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion helped. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve this problem by using the suggestion given by Shn_Android_Dev in the comment (Thank you). Apparently it was related to the (debug) file.

I was always putting the API code in `google_maps_api.xml (debug)`, as given also in the manifest file as `android:value="@string/google_maps_key"`. For some reason, however, when I was opening the app, it was telling me that the API is not correct. The wrong API shown in Logcat as an error was actually the one located in the file called `strings.xml (debug)`. So I had two different APIs in two different files. Please see picture below.

[image]

The secret lays also in `strings.xml (debug)` and `google_maps_api.xml (debug)`, as I suspected. Working all the time in debug, I had the API set there, but when generating signed APK to GooglePlay, AS was changing to `strings.xml (release)` and `google_maps.xml (release)` in the background. However, one would only access the release part if the Built Variants would be changed to Release. Otherwise, one would need to change the API key manually in the release\values folder.

The problem is now solved. The maps are now shown also on Google Play. I hope this will answer will help.